# What is the reverse of (object) array (key => value) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Is there a fast way to return a key when you know its value in PHP?

For example, if you have:

```
$Numbers = (object) array ( "0" => 0, "1" => 1, "2" => 3, "3" => 7, "4" => 13 );
```

is there a way to return:

```
echo re(13);   // Print 4
```

One way I could think of is to build a function specifically for this, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: It would have taken you half the effort used to create this question to use your favourite search engine to find the answer to this question .... poor !!

Comment: @ManseUK: Stack Overflow does NOT discourage questions that can be answered via Google. Duplicates from this site, yes, but not questions that can be answered by Google. Your views do not represent the community.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know what to search as I did not know there is a way to return only the Keys or the Values of and object array. Thank you any way for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is `array_search`:

```
$key = array_search(13, (array) $Numbers);
```

See https://www.php.net/array_search

Answer (score 3):

As several other people have mentioned, `array_search` does what you asked. But if you want an array of ALL the keys that contain the value instead of only the first, you can use `array_keys`.

```
print_r(array_keys($Numbers, 13)); // print Array ( [0] => 4 )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Yes, I know the key is in here, else I will get NULL, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/array_search

```
echo array_search($valToSearch, (array) $Numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are certain that you have unique keys:

```
$flipped = array_flip($array);
$key = $flipped[$knownValue];
return $key;
```

Otherwise, use array_search:

```
return array_search($knownValue, $array);
```

The first approach *may* be better if you do a number of lookups, and have unique values. The second approach returns the first matching key in case of multiple values.

Comment: Thank you, it's good to know there is a flip function. I guess, all the numbers will become strings. E.g. '4' => 13 will become '13' => '4' ...

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide some context with your link.